# WordPress pagination doens't work on home

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I created a WordPress template file with latest posts and pagination. But when I set this page as the home page, the pagination wont work and it'll display the first page. As a standalone page it does work. Strange! Any thoughts about this?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area clr">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article class="homepage-wrap clr">
                <?php
                /**
                    Post Content
                **/ ?>
                <?php if ( get_the_content() !== '' ) { ?>
                    <div id="homepage-content" class="entry clr">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                /**
                    Features
                **/
                $wpex_query = new WP_Query(
                    array(
                        'order'             => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
                        'post_type'         => 'features',
                        'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
                        'no_found_rows'     => true,
                    )
                );
                if ( $wpex_query->posts ) { ?>
                    <div id="homepage-features" class="clr">
                        <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>
                        <?php foreach( $wpex_query->posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                            <?php $wpex_count++; ?>
                                <?php get_template_part( 'content-features', get_post_format() ); ?>
                            <?php if ( $wpex_count == '4' ) { ?>
                                <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div><!-- #homepage-features -->
                <?php } ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <?php
                /**
                    Portfolio
                **/
                $display_count = get_theme_mod('wpex_home_portfolio_count', '8');
                $wpex_query = new WP_Query(
                    array(
                        'post_type'         => 'portfolio',
                        'posts_per_page'    => $display_count,
                        'no_found_rows'     => true,
                        'tax_query'         => wpex_home_portfolio_taxonomy(),
                    )
                );
                if ( $wpex_query->posts && '0' != $display_count ) { ?>
                    <div id="homepage-portfolio" class="clr">
                        <h2 class="heading"><span><?php _e( 'Recent Work', 'wpex' ); ?></span></h2>
                        <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>
                        <?php foreach( $wpex_query->posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                            <?php $wpex_count++; ?>
                                <?php get_template_part( 'content-portfolio', get_post_format() ); ?>
                            <?php if ( $wpex_count == '4' ) { ?>
                                <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div><!-- #homepage-portfolio -->
                <?php } ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


                <?php
                    $args = array(
                    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
                    'posts_per_page' => 4
                    );
                    query_posts($args); 
                ?>

                    <div id="homepage-blog" class="clr">
                        <h2 class="heading"><span><?php _e( 'From The Blog', 'wpex' ); ?></span></h2>
                        <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>

                        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                            <?php $wpex_count++; ?>
                                <article class="recent-blog-entry clr col span_1_of_3 col-<?php echo $wpex_count; ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    // Display post thumbnail
                                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                        <div class="recent-blog-entry-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>">
                                                <img src="<?php echo wpex_get_featured_img_url(); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div><!-- .recent-blog-entry-thumbnail -->
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <header>
                                        <h3 class="recent-blog-entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                        <ul class="post-meta clr">
                                            <li class="meta-date"><?php _e('Posted on','wpex'); ?> <span class="meta-date-text"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>                                                </li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </header>
                                    <div class="recent-blog-entry-content entry clr">
                                        <?php wpex_excerpt( 18, false ); ?>
                                    </div><!-- .recent-blog-entry-content -->
                                </article><!-- .recent-blog -->
                            <?php if ( $wpex_count == '3' ) { ?>
                                <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php wp_pagenavi();?>
                    </div><!-- #homepage-portfolio -->

                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </article><!-- #post -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `query_posts` for the `#homepage-blog` although you are - rightly so - using the `WP_Query` object in the other cases?

Comment: Hi, this is because I used an existing template and I used my knowlegde to edit it. I probably miss some knowlegde to do it the right was, @alpipego.

Comment: try changing the `query_posts` to something link `$posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );` and see what happens. (Don't forget the $posts_query in your if/while loop);

Comment: Sorry @alpipego I'm not sure how to manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have found an answer for this myself, apparently it's different when you use pagination on the frontpage. I used this and it seems to be working!:

```
if( is_front_page() ){
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 
} else {
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
}
```